# How to delegate O365 authentication to a SSO provider other than Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Here is the use case:

- User access O365 URL
- User should be challenged for authentication by a SSO / authentication provider (e.g., Okta / miniOrange / AuthPoint etc.)
- The SSO solution in turn authenticates against Azure AD (userid and Azure AD password)

What I tried and observed:

- Created a custom federated domain in Azure AD
- User now is redirected to the SSO provider
- If user is allowed to authenticate against local credential of the SSO provider, user is able to access O365
- What I need is to authenticate with Azure AD credentials (not using on-prem AD)
- I tried with ADDS as well but the problem is the moment I set the federated domain as UPN of the user, AAD does not allow to manage the user anymore including password changes

Questions:

- Other than using custom domain, is there any other way to use a non-Microsoft authentication provider?
- If I use Azure AD authentication, what are the options for using a third-party MFA provider? (E.g., OATH token)
- Is it even possible to use federated custom domain in Azure AD and then let the IdP authenticate against Azure AD (via APIs or by using AAD as IdP)?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. Other than using custom domain, is there any other way to use a non-Microsoft authentication provider?
   **Yes, some providers, such as Google, do not require custom domain names added. For more infomation take a look at [Identity Providers for External Identities.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/identity-providers)**
2. If I use Azure AD authentication, what are the options for using a third-party MFA provider? (E.g., OATH token)
   **Yes, Azure AD supports OATH tokens, FIDO2 keys and more. For more information take a look to [What authentication and verification methods are available in Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods)**
3. Is it even possible to use federated custom domain in Azure AD and then let the IdP authenticate against Azure AD (via APIs or by using AAD as IdP)?
   **That would defeat the purpose of federation.**